# Have VSCode ignore specific reference links in markdown validation

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, lint

In Visual Studio Code with [Markdown validation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/languages/markdown.md#link-validation) enabled (`markdown.validate.enabled: true`), I can ignore links to specific files that may not exist in the current context via the `markdown.validate.ignoredLinks` setting.  However, that setting does not seem to apply to reference links (e.g. `[link]: some-reference`), nor can I find a corresponding setting specific to reference links.

Why do I want this?  My specific use-case involves an extension the "standard" (CommonMark) markdown format to auto-generate a table-of-contents using the following syntax (and no, I don't expect VSCode to generate a preview of that TOC):

```markdown
[[_TOC_]]
<!-- or -->
[TOC]
```

VScode happily generates a warning for such links, namely:

> No link definition found: 'TOC' (`link.no-such-reference`)

Somewhat obviously, I can make the warning disappear I define a (bogus) TOC reference, such as:

```markdown
[toc]: bogus
```

I can also disable validation of **all** reference links (`"markdown.validate.referenceLinks.enabled": false`), but I don't want to do that.  I want to ignore the error for a specific reference, much like one can ignore a GLOB pattern for file links (`markdown.validate.ignoredLinks`).

Does anyone know of a such a setting before I submit a bug/missing-feature report?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to ignore a specfic `link.no-such-reference` warning. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I have not.  And I have not yet submitted a bug/feature-request.  If you do, post a response here, please.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same solution but did not find one either.

<strike>I have submitted an Issue against the markdown lint extension @ https://github.com/DavidAnson/vscode-markdownlint/issues/304.</strike>

**Update**: Apparently this problem is not with the markdown lint extension, but the native feature within VS Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_link-validation.  I have created this ticket instead: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194647

*Posting as an answer here to avoid others creating a duplicate if they land here first (as I did).  Once a solution has been provided, I'll edit this answer with details provided.*

Comment: Thanks for the followup with the ticket refs...